# How to determine static lib path for boost?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake

I use this for static-compiling with libboost-system and libboost-filesystem:

```
add_library(boost_system STATIC IMPORTED)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(boost_system PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/lib/libboost_system.a)

add_library(boost_filesystem STATIC IMPORTED)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(boost_filesystem PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.a)

target_link_libraries(mysuperprogram ${LIBS} boost_system boost_filesystem)
```

Problem is that on my development machine (Linux Mint 17.1) `libboost_*.a` files installed in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, but on build machine (Ubuntu 12.04.5 x64) where I need to compile it for production libraries are installed simply in `/usr/lib`.

How to determine lib path and use it in CMakeLists.txt? May be there is any system variable or something like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the find_package feature of CMake. Add the following lines to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON) 
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS boost_system REQUIRED)
link_libraries(${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Please see also: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html

Comment: Thanks. But how to do this, for example, for `libmysqlclient`?